# Nested async method blocks without await

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm not sure about what's going on here. As I understand, as soon as a method encounters the await keyword, it effectively returns, and later continues executing once the `Task` is completed. However, that is not the behavior that I am observing. I have two simple methods:

```
public static async Task<bool> Level1()
{            
    var t = await Level2();      
    Console.WriteLine("L1 done.");  
    return t;                     
}

public static async Task<bool> Level2()
{
    int delay = 10;
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    var t = new TaskFactory();

    t.StartNew(() => { Thread.Sleep(delay); });
    Console.WriteLine("L2 done.");
    return true;
}
```

And in main, I call

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Level1();
    Console.WriteLine("Main done.");
}
```

Now, I would expect `Main()` to continue executing after the call to `Level1()`, since it is not awaited, and because `Level1()` contains an await keyword. The resulting output, however, is

```
L2 done.
L1 done.
Main done.
```

Indicating that my async methods are running synchronously. Modifying `Level2()` to use the await keyword solves the problem, and the `Level1()` call no longer blocks. Why do I need to use "await" in the nested method `Level2()` method to keep `Level1()` from blocking Main?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marking a method with the async keyword doesn't make it asynchronous. It only allows to use await (and wraps the result, or exceptions with a task).

If you have an "async" method that doesn't await any asynchronous operation inside it the method is completely synchronous and will run on the calling thread.

What you're probably missing is that using `await` doesn't necessarily makes the method run asynchronously as well, using `await` on an uncompleted task does. When the task is already completed there's no reason to suspend the method. You can just get the result out of the task and keep running synchronously.

In your case since `Level2` runs synchronously. When `Level1` is ready to await its task it's already completed so `Level2` keeps running synchronously. Keep in mind that you await a task, and not a method so your code actually runs like this:

```
public static async Task<bool> Level1()
{            
    var $task = Level2(); // Runs synchronously
    var t = await $task; // Awaiting a completed task      
    Console.WriteLine("L1 done.");  
    return t;                     
}
```

Comment: This is why I am confused. Level1() does await an asynchronous method.

Comment: @user2647513 no it doesn't. It's awaiting a synchronous method becuase `Level2` isn't asynchronous. It's awaiting an already completed task. See my update.

Comment: So in order for the parent of a chain of nested async calls (Level1, in this case) to run asynchronously, some method in the chain must await a call to either TaskScheduler.StartNew() or Task.Run()?

Comment: @user2647513 In order for an async method, or any of its callers, to run asynchronously they need to await some asynchronous operation. `Task.Run` is offloading synchronous code to another thread and treating it as asynchronous, but there are actual inherently asynchronous operations (like `Task.Delay`).

Comment: I see. Digging deeper, how does the compiler determine whether an operation is asynchronous, if not with the async modifier? I'm looking at the implementation of Task.Delay (http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5848) and I don't see anything telling - except perhaps that it is missing the async modifier.

Comment: @user2647513 `Task.Delay` doesn't use the async modifier. It just returns a task that represents a delay. When you await that task the compiler converts await into code that checks whether the task completed with `GetAwaiter().IsCompleted` and if not continues synchronously.